# Why does this Fortran random number generator cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I took the following function `ran0` from the text *Numerical Recipes*.  I wrote my own program `random2` to call `ran0`.

Why does this code cause a segmentation fault?  Thanks for your time.

```
FUNCTION ran0(idum)
  INTEGER idum,IA,IM,IQ,IR,MASK
  REAL ran0,AM
  PARAMETER (IA=16807,IM=2147483647,AM=1./IM,IQ=127773,IR=2836,MASK=123459876)
  INTEGER k
  idum=ieor(idum,MASK)
  k=idum/IQ
  idum=IA*(idum-k*IQ)-IR*k
  if (idum.lt.0) idum=idum+IM
  ran0=AM*idum
  idum=ieor(idum,MASK)
  return
END FUNCTION

PROGRAM random2
  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL :: ran0
  PRINT *, ran0(6)
END PROGRAM
```

Comment: Don't do this.  None of the random number generators in Numerical recipies are great, and ran0 above is a linear congruential generator with correlations and short period.  The `random_number()` intrinsic in both gfortran and ifort are perfectly solid implementations, certainly better by any metric than the above, and there are lots of libraries out there that you can download, compile, and use ( http://www.agner.org/random/ ,  http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/testu01/tu01.html ) implementing still better PRNGs if you need those.  If you need PRNG for your computation, use good ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pass the constant 6.0 to your function as the IDUM dummy argument.  You then (attempt to) modify this argument with lines such as idum = ieor(...) etc.  You are effectively trying to modify a constant.

The value of 6.0 has been fixed for some time now  - long enough that most programmers expect to find it somewhere between 5.0 and 7.0.  Please don't try and change it.

Answer (score 2):

Extending the answer of IanH, if you partially rewrite this in more modern Fortran:

```
module my_subs

contains

FUNCTION ran0(idum)
  INTEGER, intent(inout) :: idum
  INTEGER IA,IM,IQ,IR,MASK
  REAL ran0,AM
  PARAMETER (IA=16807,IM=2147483647,AM=1./IM,IQ=127773,IR=2836,MASK=123459876)
  INTEGER k
  idum=ieor(idum,MASK)
  k=idum/IQ
  idum=IA*(idum-k*IQ)-IR*k
  if (idum.lt.0) idum=idum+IM
  ran0=AM*idum
  idum=ieor(idum,MASK)
  return
END FUNCTION

end module my_subs

PROGRAM random2
  use my_subs
  IMPLICIT NONE
  !REAL :: ran0
  PRINT *, ran0(6)
END PROGRAM
```

Identifying the argument as being both input and output with the `intent(inout)` attribute and placing the subroutine in a module and using that module to allow the compiler to check the consistency of the arguments, the compiler is likely to find this problem.  For example, gfortran outputs:

```
PRINT *, ran0(6)
              1
Error: Non-variable expression in variable definition context (actual argument to INTENT = OUT/INOUT) at (1)
```